# Simple way to run same .sql script on multiple databases at once?

Tags: sql

Is there a simple way in, say Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to run a saved .sql script on a list of databases?

Comment: There are relatively simply ways to do this in SQL Management Studio as shown below.  Seems too many useful questions are closed as "OFF TOPIC". I'm not sure what the massive paranoia is about heated 3rd party solution debates. Maybe just mark 3rd party solutions as a different type of answer and close their dialog rather than close the whole question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could execute the script against multiple databases using a batch file to execute the script using [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Yout didn't specify what version, but this is also supported natively in SQL 2008 Management Studio by right clicking on a server group in the Registered Servers window and selecting "New Query". This works against pervious version of SQL as well and mixed groups (e.g. SQL 2000, 2005 and 2008 all at once).

Red-Gate also has a tool you can purchase that does this called SQL Multi Script: http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Multi_Script/index.htm. I've never used it though.

Answer (score 1):

Freeware app to run the same query across multiple databases:
http://www.geniusconnect.com/articles/Otherproducts/2/4/9/

Answer (score 1):

One good solution can be found here:

[Executing a set of SQL Script Files (*.sql) on a Group of SQL Server Databases](http://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/executing-a-set-of-sql-script-files-sql-on-a-group-of-sql-server-databases/)

Comment: This is actually bad advice. Uses xp_cmdshell which introduces security risks and requires increased permissions to turn functionality on/off.

Answer (score 0):

This always has been a big hassle for us.  We have been looking for a tool to do exactly this.  We tried both www.redgate.com and www.queryblaster.com.  We decided to go with queryblaster, it was the easiest to use out of the two. Both of these software applications allow you to run scripts on multiple databases at once.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS Tools Pack is a nice option, particularly for pre-2012 database servers, since it is free.

http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

Comment: The feature: "Run on Multiple Targets" - http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=6